# Reverse an integer without losing 0's in input

Tags: java, int, reverse

I have the following code that reverses an integer input. However, if I enter input with zeroes at the beginning e.g. 01234, it will return me the integer 4321 instead of 43210. I've looked at other solutions but they all solve the problem by getting the input as a String and then reversing the string. However, I need my input to be of type int.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this?

```
public static int reverseInputNumber(int num){
    int reverse = 0;
    while(num!=0) {
        reverse = (reverse*10)+num%10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: How about getting it as int and converting it to String and reversing it and getting back as int

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806126/java-reverse-int-value

Comment: @arynaq that's what he's already doing, but doesn't solve the leading 0 issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers store an integer value, not an encoding of a particular representation of an integral value. So in order to really get what you want you're talking about reversing the representation of an integer.

EDIT: I thought I'd add some code to solve the solution using Strings.

```
public static int reverseInputNumber(int num)
{
    String reverse = StringBuilder(num + "").reverse().toString();
    return reverse;
}
```

Second Edit: Actually even this code won't do what you want it to do. By taking an int as a parameter you're already losing the original representation of the integer. It's accurate to say that there is no function that can take just an integer parameter and return something with the reverse of it's original representation. You would need to deal solely in strings or some other more appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 1):

In java, using a zero as the most significant digit, it interpreters the number as an octal number. So `01234` gets converted to:

```
4 + 3 x 8 + 2 x 8^(2) + 1 x 8^(3) = 668
```

So you are better off with using one of the convert-to-string methods as in the other answers.

**Edit:** Here is a version without StringBuffer etc.:

```
public String getReversed(int number) {
    char[] digitArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    String strNum = "";

    for (int i = digitArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        strNum += digitArray[i];
    }
    return strNum;
}
```

**2nd edit:** Reversing a `char` array and then create the `String` after finished reversing, because of a possible creation of number of `O(n^2)` operations that could be a problem for the garbage collector.

```
public String getReversed(int number) {
    char[] digitArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    char[] reversedDigitArray = new char[digitArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < digitArray.length; i++) {
        reversedDigitArray[i] = digitArray[digitArray.length - i - 1];
    }
    return new String(reversedDigitArray);
}
```

**3rd Edit:** Swaps chars with in-place algorithm.

```
public static String getReversed(int number) {
    char[] digitArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    int count = digitArray.length - 1;
    char tmp;

    for (int i = (count-1) >> 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        tmp = digitArray[i];
        digitArray[i] = digitArray[count - i];
        digitArray[count - i] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(digitArray);
}
```

Comment: It might be better to simply reverse the char[] in place and then use the String(Char[]) constructor, since as it stands there is the possibility of creating a number of O(N^2) operation with a lot of garbage collection.

Comment: @VarunMadiath Is this better?

Comment: I'd say it is, further improvement would be to sort it in place, but the number of digits in maximum value of int makes the penalty here too small to worry about.

Comment: Not a problem, I just updated my answer to describe why neither of our approaches would work.

Comment: I was looking through your 3rd edit, and I was wondering why you use the right shift? I can't seem to see a reason, care to explain?

Comment: I'm basically doing it instead of using `count / 2`, by shifting the bit i get the same effect. But I think it's faster? I have seen it before somewhere, so it's a habit I have absorbed when I iterate over half of an array.

Comment: But maybe the readability of the code should be prioritized in this particular use case?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is required to be an `int` then convert it to `String` and reverse that.

```
String reverseInt(int in){
    String a = Integer.toString(in);
    return new StringBuilder(a).reverse().toString();
}
```

If your output is required to be an `int` there is no way to have a leading `0`.