# palindromes of sums less than 30, help to optimize my code

Tags: python, optimization

On my way of studying Python i stacked on the problem:
I have to count all numbers from **0** to **130000** which are palindromes, but they should be palindromes after sum of the number and its reversed version. For example: 

 `i` = 93 

93 + 39 = 132

132 + 231 = 363

`count_of_palindromes` should count all `i` which are palindromes after **1** or more iterations of summing, but less than **50**.

I've already written the code but it's too way difficult to run on my PC, Python stops responding :( 

Any advices how to optimize my code?

```
        count_of_palindromes = 0
        for i in range(0,130000):
            trying = 0
            if (i == int(str(i)[::-1])) != True:
                trying += 1
                sum = i + int(str(i)[::-1])
                while trying <= 50:
                    while (sum == int(str(sum)[::-1])) != True:
                        trying += 1
                        sum += int(str(sum)[::-1])                
                    if trying > 0 and trying <= 50:
                        count_of_palindromes += 1
                        break
        print(count_of_palindromes)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's tidy your code up a bit first for readability.  We'll just take some of the syntax heavy string stuff and encapsulate it.

```
def reverse(n):
    return int(str(n)[::-1])

def is_palindrome(n):
    return n == reverse(n)
```

That's better.  I think your problem is the second nested while loop.  It runs until it finds a palindrome, then checks if it found it in the first fifty tries.  You want it to run up to fifty times, then give up.  I think the best way would be a second for loop

```
count_of_palindromes = 0
for i in range(130000):
    for tries in range(50):
        if(is_palindrome(i)):
            counter += 1
            break
        else:
            i = i + reverse(i)
print(count_of_palindromes)
```

There are some more ways of speeding this up by avoiding string operations and replacing them with math, but that's overkill for this.  I was a little unclear on how your problem wants you to treat natural palindromes, so you may need to modify this solution

Answer (score 0):

This solution has a lot of conversions so it may not be the best solution but regardless it is a solution. have a look at this post he has a seemingly much better method of reversing integers without conversion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806212/1642546

If you combine my code and that posts code. you probably will have a faster solution, but you must benchmark it to see.

```
token = 0
for x in range(130000):
   reversed = str(x)[::-1]
   original = str(x)
   sum = int(reversed) + int(original)
   if str(sum) == str(sum)[::-1]:
      token+=1
print(token)
```

Comment: The question actually was not how to reverse a number but how to easier and faster loop to calculate the sums..

Comment: EXACTLY.I added an extra line in my original post to clarify. My solution is simpler and probably is faster, but what I am saying is he can do better if he avoids conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in the code, that made the program almost ifinite :) 

The correct code (in my opinion is below)

```
count_of_palindromes = 0
for i in range(12814):
    if (i == int(str(i)[::-1])) != True:
        trying = 1
        sum = i + int(str(i)[::-1])
        while trying <= 50:
            while (sum == int(str(sum)[::-1])) != True and trying <=50:
                trying += 1
                sum += int(str(sum)[::-1])                
            if trying > 0 and trying <= 50:
                count_of_palindromes += 1
                break
print(count_of_palindromes)
```