# How to use input from another method?

Tags: java

I have an assignment that requires me to write a program that reverses the order of a positive integer that a user enters i.e 1234 becomes 4321.

The program also has to validate that the input is a positive integer. Both of these have to be done in separate methods.

I have done the validation part which is included below. I want to put the user input in an array but I have no idea how to use the validated number in a separate method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class order {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userEntry;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
        userEntry = keyboard.nextLine();

        userEntry = validate (userEntry);
        int original = Integer.parseInt(userEntry);
        System.out.println("The original number is: "+ original);

    }

    public static String validate (String userInput) { 

        int userInputLength = userInput.length();
        int counter = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (userInputLength == 0) {                                                          
            System.out.println("That is not a valid integer. Try again");
            userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
            userInputLength = userInput.length();       
        }

        while (counter < userInputLength) {

            if (Character.isLetter(userInput.charAt(counter))) {

                System.out.println("That is not a valid integer. Try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                userInputLength = userInput.length();
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            counter++;
            }

            while (userInputLength == 0) {

                System.out.println("That is not a valid integer. Try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                userInputLength = userInput.length();
            }
        }
        return userInput;   
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by reverse order? do you mean that you need to output yx if input is xy??

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 that is correct.

Comment: Why not just validate with a regex?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to pass the value returned by validate() method to some other method?

Comment: @Arun yes that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value returned by your `validate()` method and then pass it to another method in this case the `reverseString()` method. `stringDigits` is the array that has digits of the string.

In your main method

```
 String validatedString = validate(userInput);
 String reversedString = reverseString(validatedString);
 int[] stringInDigits = new int[userInput.length()];
 stringInDigits = getElementsAsArray(userInput);
```

`reversedString` variable will contain the reversed value.

Assuming that you will pass the original number as a String. Loop through the string in the reverse order.

Reverse String Method

```
   public String reverseString(String aString){
       String reverseString = "" ;
       int index = aString.length()-1;
       while(index >= 0){
           char myCharacter = aString.charAt(index);
           reverseString = reverseString.concat(""+myCharacter) ;
           index--;
       }
       return reverseString;
   }
```

Store Digits in Numeric String to an Array

Declare an array of size equal to string length. Loop through the string character by character and put it into an array

```
   public int[] getElementsAsArray(String aString){
       int[] digits = new int[aString.length()];
       for(int i=0;i<aString.length();i++){
           digits[i]=Integer.parseInt(""+aString.charAt(i));
       }
       return digits;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does what I was looking for and also answers my question. The only problem is that I need to also need to display the even numbers and odd numbers separately, which is why I initially asked how to take the input in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808804/2815219) method to reverse a number:

```
public int reverseInt(int input)
{
    long reversedNum = 0;

    long input_long = input;

    while (input_long != 0)
    {
        reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + input_long % 10;
        input_long = input_long / 10;
    }

    if (reversedNum > Integer.MAX_VALUE || reversedNum < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return (int)reversedNum;
}
```

---

FYI, Instead of your `validate()` method as you have written now, you can create a method to get integer value. If the inputted value is parsed successfully as integer, then it will return integer, otherwise user will get prompt again. This will reduce a lot of boilerplate:

```
public static int getInteger() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(keyboard.next());
        } catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
            System.out.print("That is not a valid integer. Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

And call it from main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userEntry;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    int original = getInteger();

    System.out.println("The original number is: "+ original);
    System.out.println("The reversed number is: "+ reverse(original));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the required function:

```
public static int reverse (int userInpu) { 
 int lastDigit,res=0;

 while (userInpu != 0)
 {    
     lastDigit = userInpu % 10;
     if(lastDigit % 2 != 0)
     {     
            res = res * 10 + lastDigit;

     }
      userInpu = userInpu / 10; 
 }

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the characters and place them in the array by index (`for` loop). Index 0 in the input string would have an index of `userInputLength - 1 - 0` in the array. The second one would have an index of `userInputLength - 1 - 1`. Third is `userInputLength - 1 - 2`. Etc.