# Simple way of reversing a number in java

Tags: java

Hi everyone just had a simple quick question and would like some quick feedback. What would be a plain simple way for a beginner programmer to take for instance a 3 digit integer such as 745 and reverse it and print it out as 547? thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java reverse int value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806126/java-reverse-int-value)

Comment: Not that question.  It has "vandalism" problems.

Comment: @StephenC what do do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that the linked Q was changed in a way that made its accepted answer nonsensical (and plain  wrong).  I have reverted the edit ... but now the Q is no longer relevant to >>this<< Q.  Hopefully a moderator will sort out this mess.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your integer value to String, then using the `reverse` method of `StringBuilder`

Comment: @GRC can you tell me you smarter idea?

Comment: there is simple mathematical way without converting it to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder("745").reverse().toString());
```