# Can Anyone tell me the reason, why my method does not pass the sample test cases?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

The following is my solution to *Beautiful Days at the Movies* problem on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-days-at-the-movies/problem).

Basically I need to implement the following method.

```java
int beautifulNum(int from, int to, int k)
```

The method should return the number of beautiful numbers between `from` and `to`.

A number is beautiful if the result of its difference with its reverse is divisible by `k`.

Example:
`beautifulNum(20, 23, 6)` should return 2.

- Reverse of 20 is 2. Difference is 18 which is divisible by 6 so 20 is a beautiful number.
- Reverse of 21 is 12. Difference is 9 which is not divisible by 6 hence 21 is not a beautiful number.
- Similarly, 22 is a beautiful number and 23 is not.
- Therefore `beautifulNum(20, 23, 6)` should return 2.

However, the following does not work, why?

```java
public static int beautifulNum(int from, int to, int k) {
    int reverse = 0; 
    int num = 0;
    for (int n = from; n <= to; n++) {
        while(n != 0) {  
            int remainder = n % 10;  
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;  
            n = n/10;  
        }
        int rreverse = (n-reverse)/k;
        if (rreverse % 1 == 0 ) {
            num++;
        }      
    }     
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Because it returns a different result than what is expected.

Comment: yes, of course, but how?

Comment: Note that `rreverse % 1` is always equal to 0.

Comment: Moreover, you should avoid modifying the loop index `n` in the loop.

Comment: @Damien I already putted the link which leads to the problem that the code suppose to solve

Comment: And `reverse` should be reinitialised to 0 for every new `n`.

Comment: @Damien Thank you very much for your feedback, I am working on it meanwhile

Comment: I think this line `int rreverse = (n-reverse)/k;` should be `int rreverse = n-reverse;` and the following `if` should be `if(rreverse % k == 0)`. The expression inside the `if` checks if `rreverse` is evenly divisible by `k` which I believe determines if the number "is beautiful".

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to reverse a number in Java. Refer to [Java reverse an int value without using array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806126/java-reverse-an-int-value-without-using-array). In the below code I chose to convert the number to a string and use method `reverse` of class `StringBuilder`.

Then you need to subtract the reversed number from the original number and then you need to see whether the result of that subtraction is divisible by the method parameter `k`. In other words you need to check whether `difference % k == 0` where `difference` is the result of subtracting the reversed number from the original number.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static int beautifulNum(int from, int to, int k) {
        int reverse = 0;
        int num = 0;
        for (int n = from; n <= to; n++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(n));
            sb.reverse();
            reverse = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
            int rreverse = n - reverse;
            if (rreverse % k == 0) {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(beautifulNum(20, 23, 6));
    }
}
```